# Heading and paragraph text together without space

Tags: text, margin, space, paragraph, gaps-in-visuals

I have -

```
<p>some text as 'intro'</p>
<h1>Big Text</h1>
<p>some text as 'outro'</p>
```

I have this set out on a background image, I have styled margins and fitted the text inside properly, but I want to bunch up ALL text so there is little gap - line-height would ruin it and I have tried seperate div tags but no luck - what is the best chosen css method for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean with 1. I have styled margins and fitted the text inside properly, 2.  I want to bunch up ALL text so there is little gap, 3. line-height would ruin it?

Comment: 1, used CSS to ensure text layout is within background image, 2, text vertically 'tight' together (on top of each other) 3, akin to line-height but is there a better way? ie, you cannot bunch the <p> and <hx> together as they are separate html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you require the use of those elements you could use negative margins:

```
<p>some text as 'intro'</p>
<h1 style="margin: -15px 0 -15px">Big Text</h1>
<p>some text as 'outro'</p>
```

A better way is probably to separate the different lines by line breaks and to style the 'header' line, like so:

```
<p>some text as 'intro'<br />
<span style="font-size: 200%; font-weight: bold;">Big Text</span><br />
some text as 'outro'</p>
```